# How do I add a hyperlink using python script?

Tags: python

I am trying to add a hyperlink to an email I'm sending through python send mail. I'd like to add a link after blah blah blah. thanks in advance!

here is what i have so far:

[code i already have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWn1v.png)

Comment: Put code here as text.

Answer (score 1):

```
email = "test@gmail.com"
"this is my e-mail:{email}".format(
   email=email,
)
```

result is

```
this is my e-mail:test@gmail.com
```

is this what you want?
i need more detail description

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for that purpose.

Example:

```
link = 'https://google.com'
mymail = 'Hello friend!\nCheck this out {}'.format(link)
print mymail

>>> Hello friend!
>>> Check this out https://google.com
```